# How to use a List in Do-loop?

Tags: list-manipulation

My program produces a list that looks exactly like this:

```
listr = {{i[1], 0, 13}, {i[2], 0, 21}, {i[3], 0, 41}, {i[4], 0, 5}};
```

Now I want to use this list in a [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html)-Loop as follows:

```
Do[something, {i[1], 0, 13}, {i[2], 0, 21}, {i[3], 0, 41}, {i[4], 0, 5}]
```

but

```
Do[something, listr]
```

doesn't work. How do I make the Do-loop understand that `listr` is to be used?

Comment: `Do[something, Sequence @@ listr // Evaluate]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, march. It worked!

Comment: How about `Do[something, ##] & @@ listr`?